# "existing connection was forcibly closed" error on sending email in .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, sendmail, smtpclient

I have asp.net web-site. I'm sending email through `SMTPClient`.  And from time to time I've gotten this error:

```
 InnerException = System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: 
    An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> 
       System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.DelegatedStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.BufferedReadStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLines(SmtpReplyReader caller, Boolean oneLine)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLine(SmtpReplyReader caller)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReader.ReadLine()
   at System.Net.Mail.CheckCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, String& response)
   at System.Net.Mail.DataStopCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.OnClose(Object sender, EventArgs args)
   at System.Net.ClosableStream.Close()
   at System.Net.Mail.MailWriter.Close()
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message).
```

Code:

```
 SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpserverwwwpo"]);
    try
    {
        NetworkCredential basicCredential =
            new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtp_user_name"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtp_password"]);
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtpClient.Credentials = basicCredential;
    }
    catch
    {
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    }

    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
    msg.Subject = subject;
    msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(someEmail));
    msg.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["from_email_address"]);
    msg.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/html");
    msg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

try{
        smtpClient.Send(msg);
} 
catch(Exception ex)
{
 //write log 
}
```

}

What reasons can cause it?

Comment: Looks like the SMTP server closed the connection.  Maybe check the server's logs?

Comment: are you sending email using sockets or using smtp / System.Net.Mail ? what code do you have please post.. sending emails via .NET is fairly straight forward and simple

Comment: You might be getting kicked by a spam prevention mechanism on the remote host. How rapidly are you generating emails? What kind of mail server are you sending to (Exchange, sendmail, etc.)?

Comment: Who are you sending the email to.. I see a From but not a To aslo does your SMTP email Client really require network Creds..?

Comment: you could clean up a large portion of your code by configuring SmtpClient via system.net.mail in the config file rather than appsettings. this doesn't have any affect on your problem, but would make the code much cleaner.

Comment: I'm seeing this also, with the key phrase (from my point of view) being "FROM TIME TO TIME." On Friday, an app user went through the process that initiates an email 24 times, and 3 of them failed. I'm used to batting 1.000, but 0.875 is good enough that my own code seems affirmed. (This started a few months ago, on .NET 2.0, I've updated the app to .NET 3.5, but same deal.)

Answer (score 3):

MailMessage is disposable. you could try wrapping it in a using statement.

```
using(var message = new MailMessage {Subject ="...", Body="..."})
{
   message.To.Add("email address");
   new SmtpClient().Send(message)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do believe that it has little to do with the actual code that you've posted, and everything to do with the volume and content of your requests, as interpreted by the server you're connecting to. Forcibly closing a connection is a willful act and not a random error, which means the server is choosing to do so based on some conditions being satisfied.

As has been suggested above, perhaps you are hitting some limit unknown to you; or, perhaps the remote server is particularly busy and closes connections (and doesn't return the proper error code for that case).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should set SmtpClient.EnableSsl to false.

Answer (score 0):

where are you assigning the SMTP Client's Host name ...?

what if you changed your code to use the following not sure if Network Credentials are needed I am not familiar with your specs but this code I tested using my stuff just tried it and it works..

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
message.To.Add("youremailAddress");
message.Subject = "This is the Subject line";
message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("From@online.microsoft.com");
message.Body = "This is the message body";
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("yoursmtphost");
smtp.Send(message);
```

Comment: Application is on production.
And need to set credential.

Comment: Ok, so that means if you are not a valid network user or have a valid system account then emails will fail if one tries to send..? The same code example can still be utilized.. I could be wrong but why do you add new MailAddress when all you need to do is pass the email address in the Add() portion..?

Answer (score -1):

SMTPClient class implement IDisposable interface.
whenever Type implements IDisposable then you should use **Using(){}** Statement.

eg-

```
using (SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient(smtpConfig.SmtpMailServer))
                    {
                       //your code
                    }
```